# Moment.js and add pm/am and merge month, day with hour minute PLUS am or pm

Tags: javascript, momentjs

So, I am doing this;

```
Moment(startDate).add({ hour: startHour, minute:startMin})
```

and I need to have those hour/minute either be AM or PM. I have that data, but instead of me doing a test such as

```
 (ampm === 'pm' ? startHour + 12 etc...
```

Is there an additional "add parameter" I can add and Moment will do the conversion for me? So, if startHour is 2, it really could be either 2 or 14 depending if it is am or pm. I want Moment to figure that out depending on whether it is am or pm, that I pass it. I am trying to get out the full iso format for all.

Comment: `add()` adds the number of hours/minutes specified to the date, it doesn't set them. I think you want [`set()`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/get-set/set/). However, that takes 0-23 for the hour portion. It's a bit confusing where the `ampm` variable you have in your second code snippet is coming from...

Comment: I am setting that myself.. If a user wants to set their own hours/minutes, most people are comfortable with a 12 hour timeframe. Most people don't know what 22 or 15 represents. The AM/PM, they select. Then I convert that. But yea, I want to "add" them as I am gonna convert to a different form and set in db

Comment: Ok, so it this for a date/time selector or something? I would suggest concatenating the hour, minute, and am/pm to a string and parse it. More straightforward, IMO. Moment has great parsing utilities. The add thing confuses me. If startDate has a time component, like 02:30, and you "add" { hour: 2, minute: 15 } to it, you'll end up with 04:45, not 02:15. That could very well be what you want, but then am/pm doesn't really enter into it...